# Permalinks settings page blank

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

My site is giving a 500 error and I've been trying various ways to fix it.  First,  I'm trying to reset permalinks, but the options-permalink.php page is totally BLANK.  Unlike [all the other solutions](http://www.scott-benton.com/fixing-the-wordpress-permalink-blank-page-issue/) I've found, the whole page is blank, it's NOT a WP admin sidebar showing with blank content. 
Is there another way I can reset the permalinks without going through the admin interface?  Or another solution?

I've checked the .htaccess file and it seems fine, I've renamed it which didn't solve this, and I've even replaced it with the standard WP one.  I've checked file permissions too and they seem fine.

If anyone has encountered this and could help me I'd appreciate it.

Edit:  I've downloaded a clone of my site using Duplicator.  I installed it on my localhost using MAMP.  It worked out the box, no issues.
I then deleted the original on my remote host, including the database, and then installed the same clone.  I still get the 500 error.   This would suggest it's not a database error.

Comment: In your `wp-config.php` add the line `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);`, or make sure it's set to `true` if it's already defined and set to `false`. Then, you can `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );` to show errors and `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` will create a file called `wp-content/debug.log` that will log errors. I would start debugging like that to find out what's going on.

Comment: A `500` error is just Apache/Nginx's was of saying something bad happened in PHP, don't know what it is, look at the PHP error logs for the actual error

Comment: Possibly dumb question: Is it just the permalinks page that's blank/giving the 500 error, or is every other page having that problem too?

Comment: It's just that page on the back end, all others are loading.  Front end has no pages loading.

Comment: I enabled debugging and got  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) public_html/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1758

Comment: I can't find any errors in my host's error logs, so I'm stuck.  I tried changing PHP versions on the server, but that didn't help.  I've downloaded a backup of the site and I'm going to try and rebuild it locally.

Comment: @RexTheRunt deactivate all plugins and then try or Increase PHP Memory Limit in WordPress for ex. place this code in `wp-config.php` before `‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.’` `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact your hosting provider to increase `php memory limit` and `max execution time`

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you get Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted then place this code in `wp-config.php` before `‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.’` `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );` or deactivate all plugins and then try.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually flush rewrite rules with [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

It sounds like your problem is more than just the rewrite rules, however.